# How to have a subscriber in a REST API?

Tags: java, rest, publish-subscribe

Consider a request coming into your web server, calling a REST API. This request is having a job for the server which is time-consuming. So the web server code will delegate the job to some other server to provide a scalable solution. This scenario is usually implemented using a Publisher-Subscriber pattern.

So far so good, but what if I want to keep the request hanging for the result? I can turn the Publisher-Subscriber the other way around so now my REST API code will be waiting for some publisher to be notified when the results are ready.

The problem with this scenario is that subscribing for a notification is done in an asynchronous way (which on its own is perfect). So implementing a REST API in Spring waiting for a notification from RabbitMQ would look like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/url", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity url()
{
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost("localhost");
    Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
    String command = "Job Description";
    channel.basicPublish("", "Heavy Worker", null, command.getBytes());

    Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel)
    {
        @Override
        public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body)
            throws IOException
        {
            String result = new String(body, "UTF-8");
            //return the result as the HTTP response
        }
    };
    channel.basicConsume("Heavy Job Result", true, consumer);
}
```

The problem that I'm trying to illustrate in above snippet is that after `channel.basicConsume("Heavy Job Result", true, consumer);` the response will be returned to the client and Java won't be waiting for the `"Heavy Job Result"` to be prepared.

Is there a known practice how to keep the request hanging for a message in a non-polling way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution will depend on how long it takes for your heavy job to complete. If it completes in less time than your server timeout is configured for, then all you have to do is not block your web IO by returning a `CompletableFuture` or a `ListentableFuture` like so:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/url", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity> url() {
  return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    // do your computations here
  });
}
```

Spring will handle the rest for you.

If it takes longer than your server timeout, then you could use WebSockets to handle sending messages from the server to the client upon job completion.
Check out [Spring WebSocket Support](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html). The flow would be:

1. receive request
2. hand it off to a long running processor in a new thread (e.g. CompletableFuture.runAsync())
3. return a response immediately after kicking off this new thread
4. once the job finishes, you send a message to the front-end that it is completed with whatever data you want to include

Comment: @Mehran - if you find the answer useful, please accept.